# Changing a specific part of a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

In C#, I got a string which looks in the following format:

```
a number|a number|a number,a number
```

for example: 1|2|3,4

I consider each number as the different part of the string. in the previous example, 1 is the first part, 2 is the second and so on.

I want to be able to replace a specific part of the string given an index of the part I want to change.

It's not that hard to do it with `String.Split` but that part with the comma makes it tedious since then i need to check if the index is 3 or 4 and then also separate with the comma.
Is there a more elegant way to do a switch of a specific part in the string? maybe somehow with a regular expression?

EDIT: I will add some requirements which I didn't write before:

What if I want to for example take the 3rd part of the string and replace it with the number there and add it 2. for example 1|2|3,4 to 1|2|5,4 where the 5 is NOT a constant but depends on the input string given.

Comment: Can you show some sample output please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the following method

```
static string Replace(string input, int index, string replacement)
{
    int matchIndex = 0;
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\d+", m => matchIndex++ == index ? replacement : m.Value);
}
```

Usage:

```
string input = "1|2|3,4";
string output = Replace(input, 1, "hello"); // "1|hello|3,4
```

As [Eric Herlitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296568/eric-herlitz) suggested, you can use other regex, the negative of delimiters. For example, if you expect `,` and `|` delimiters, you can replace `\d+` by `[^,|]+` regex. If you expect `,`, `|` and `#` delimiters, you can use `[^,|#]` regex.

If you need to do some mathematical operations, you're free to do so:

```
static string Replace(string input, int index, int add)
{
    int matchIndex = 0;
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\d+", m => matchIndex++ == index ? (int.Parse(m.Value) + add).ToString() : m.Value );
}
```

Example:

```
string input = "1|2|3,4";
string output = Replace(input, 2, 2); // 1|2|5,4
```

You can even make it generic:

```
static string Replace(string input, int index, Func<string,string> operation)
{
    int matchIndex = 0;
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\d+", m => matchIndex++ == index ? operation(m.Value) : m.Value);
}
```

Example:

```
string input = "1|2|3,4";
string output = Replace(input, 2, value => (int.Parse(value) + 2).ToString()); // 1|2|5,4
```

Comment: This is assuming the input string always will be digits

Comment: Well, by given specification it is `a number`. It's always possible to change regex from `\d+` to `[^,|]+` or similar to handle non-number cases.

Comment: May I suggest that you change to the other pattern, it's a bit more readable and modifiable in that case. +1 for an elegant solution anyway! :)

Comment: the string will always contain a number between the '|'
This is really close to what I want but I didn't specify everything in my question. What if I want to for example take the 3rd part of the string and replace it with the number + 2. for example 1|2|3,4 to 1|2|5,4 where the 5 isn't a constant but depends on the input string given

Comment: @YonatanNir I added sample to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex.Split for the input and Regex.Match to collect your delimiters

```
string input = "1|2|3,4,5,6|7,8|9";
string pattern = @"[,|]+";

// Collect the values
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

// Collect the delimiters
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

// Replace anything you like, i.e.
substrings[3] = "222";

// Rebuild the string
int i = 0;
string newString = string.Empty;
foreach (string substring in substrings)
{
    newString += string.Concat(substring, matches.Count >= i + 1 ? matches[i++].Value : string.Empty);
}
```

This will output `"1|2|3,222,5,6|7,8|9"`

Comment: How are you going to join the string back with the original delimiters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (tested):

```
public static string Replace(string input, int value, int index)
{
       string pattern = @"(\d+)|(\d+)|(\d+),(\d+)";

       return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match =>
       {
            if (match.Index == index * 2) //multiply by 2 for | and , character.
            {
                return value.ToString();
            }

            return match.Value;
      });
 }
```

Usage example:

```
string input = "1|2|3,4";
string output = Replace(input, 9, 1);
```

Updated with new requirement:

```
public static string ReplaceIncrement(string input, int incrementValue, int index)
{
            string pattern = @"(\d+)|(\d+)|(\d+),(\d+)";

            return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match =>
            {
                if (match.Index == index * 2)
                {
                    return (int.Parse(match.Value) + incrementValue).ToString();
                }

                return match.Value;
            });
 }
```

Comment: I've added a bit more requirements if you want to try them as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "1|2|3|4,5,6|7,8|9|23|29,33";

        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceByIndex(input, "hello", 23));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static string ReplaceByIndex(string input, string replaceWith, int index)
    {
        int indexStart = input.IndexOf(index.ToString());

        int indexEnd = input.IndexOf(",", indexStart);
        if (input.IndexOf("|", indexStart) < indexEnd)
            indexEnd = input.IndexOf("|", indexStart);

        string part1 = input.Substring(0, indexStart);
        string part2 = "";
        if (indexEnd > 0)
        {
            part2 = input.Substring(indexEnd, input.Length - indexEnd);
        }

        return part1 + replaceWith + part2;
    }
```

This is assuming the numbers are in ascending order.

Comment: What if they add other delimiters, i.e ; # !, not a very scalable pattern